# Правильное использование видов коллекций в c#

Tags: c#, коллекции

Начал разбираться с основными видами коллекций в c#. Хотел бы спросить, когда можно использовать те или иные интерфейсы коллекции при взаимодействии с методами.

1. Когда существует действительная необходимость возвращать `IEnumerable<T>` из функции, и, соответственно, когда принято передавать в качестве аргумента именно `IEnumerable<T>`?
2. Является ли это хорошим решением (или даже хорошей практикой) принимать и/или возвращать `IReadOnlyList<T>` если данная функция не изменяет переданного списка и результат работы функции также не должен быть изменен (т.е. коллекция, возвращаемая функцией, не должна быть потом в программе изменена)?
3. Безопасней ли передавать и/или возвращать `IReadOnlyList<T>` чем `IEnumerable<T>` в конексте возможного далее множественного итерирования?
4. С чем из `IReadOnlyList<T>` или `IEnumerable<T>` лучше взаимодействовать при работе/разработке собственных LINQ функций при наличии условия неизменяемости передаваемой коллекции и последующей неизменяемости возвращаемой?

Я понимаю, что под IReadOnly.... (List, Collection) подразумевается коллекция, доступная только для чтения, т.е. нельзя в нее ничего добавить, однако внутреннее состояние объектов в ней изменить можно.

Вопросы возникли после прочтения соответствующей статьи на Хабре: https://habr.com/ru/post/193774/

Comment: Если будете делать только итерирование и только один раз - используйте IEnumerable<T>. IReadOnlyList я много пробовал, но практических выгод на небольших и средних проектах не ощутил, а время отнимает, поэтому я лично не рекомендую. Подкину вот что по теме, почитайте вот тут комментарии: https://habr.com/en/post/466931/#comment_20607369

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Передача коллекций в метод.

**Смысл кода должен быть понятен с первого взгляда.**

Используем чужую библиотеку. Видим метод:

```
void Foo(List<int> list)
```

Что происходит внутри метода с этим списком? Изменяет ли автор его? Добавляет или удаляет элементы? Можем ли мы *после* вызова этого метода использовать эту коллекцию, рассчитывая, что она не изменилась?
Конечно, всё это должно быть описано в документации к методу (библиотеке). Придётся читать...

А если сигнатура будет:

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
```

Тут сразу ясно, что коллекция внутри не может быть изменена. Можно даже не заглядывать в документацию.

Естественно, если суть метода заключается именно в *изменении* коллекции, то используем `ICollection`, `IList` или прочий минимально необходимый тип.

**Код должен быть безопасным и надёжным.**

А что, если мы сомневаемся в авторах библиотеки? Ведь ничто не запрещает сделать так:

```
void Foo(IEnumerable<int> enumerable)
{
    if (enumerable is List<int>)
    {
        var list = (List<int>)enumerable;
        list.Add(...);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Мы передали некий список в этот метод, где он - внезапно! - был изменён, на что мы не рассчитывали.

А вот если используется сигнатура:

```
void Foo(IReadOnlyCollection<int> readOnlyCollection)
```

то безопасность гарантирована. Конечно, вызывать нужно не так:

```
Foo(list);
```

а так:

```
Foo(list.AsReadOnly());
```

В этом случае, приведение ридонли коллекции к любому другому типу вызовет исключение.

---

2. Возврат коллекций из метода.

На протяжении долгих лет в разных книгах, статьях, блогах, в документации и на форумах рекомендовалось возвращать *конкретный* тип. То есть:

```
List<int> GetNumbers()
```

Внутри метода что-то делается, данные откуда-то получаются, как-то вычисляются и какую коллекцию наиболее удобно было использовать автору кода, ту он и возвращал. Если она совпала с ожиданиями того, кто будет использовать этот метод - замечательно - не нужно делать никаких преобразований. Например, можно сразу в этот список добавлять элементы.

Но по неведомой причине в последнее время всё чаще стали возвращать абстрактные типы: `IEnumerable` и т. п. Без всяких объяснений. Причём внутри метода обычно что-то наподобине:

```
IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers()
{
    List<int> list = ...
    return list.AsEnumerable();
}
```

Хорошо, если нам нужно просто перечислить элементы. Но если нужно менять коллекцию, придётся *копировать* данные:

```
var list = GetNumbers().ToList();
```

Это и ненужный расход памяти и лишняя нагрузка на процессор.

Кто-то может сказать: автор метода не хотел, чтобы его коллекцию меняли. Извините, но после того, как данные покинули метод, они уже не в его власти.

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, если не трудно, когда стоит опасаться использовать IEnumerable<T> из за возможной повторной (многократной) итерации. Лучше не возвращать из функции тип (интерфейс) IEnumerable<T>?

Comment: @PracticeMakesPerfect - возвращать следует тот тип, который получился сам по себе внутри метода. Имеется массив - возвращаем массив. Имеется список - возвращаем список. Имеется IEnumerable - возвращаем его. Не нужно делать лишних кастов. Кто использует этот метод, сам решит, нужно ли принудительно материализовать IEnumerable (вызовом ToList()/ToArray()) или нет.

Comment: 'но после того, как данные покинули метод, они уже не в его власти' категорически с вами не согласен:)

Comment: Возьмем объект "Машина", мы на ней можем ездить, можем закрывать ее...но нам нак же хочется знать, какая резина на ее колесах...мы спрашиваем коллекцию ее колес, она отдет нам список (потому что заботиться о нас и знает что нам чаще всего захочеться обращаться к ним по индексу)...и тут выговорите что теперь эта коллекция в нашей власти и мы можем ее менять как нам захочется? То есть менять машине колеса? без ее ведома?, а как же инвариант производитель машины разрешает ставить калеса только диамером 16-18"...

Comment: вот именно для этого и нужно использовать ReadOnly, чтобы защитить себя от изменений моего состояния без моего ведома

Comment: @skingreek - в данном теме речь о _коллекциях_, а не об _объектах_ в этих коллекциях. Машина - объект. Ридонли коллекции никак не помогут предотвратить изменение _объектов_ внутри себя. Для этой цели служат неизменяемые (immutable) объекты.

Comment: @skingreek - коллекция колес - это коллекция колес. Она никак не соотносится с конкретной машиной. Поэтому, да, мы имеем полное право добавить или удалить колеса в/из эту коллекцию и т. п. А вот когда мы будем присваивать эту коллекцию конкретному экземпляру машины - тут необходимы проверки на валидность.

Comment: Объект "Машина" возвращает коллекию колес которые в свою очередь являються ValueObject(структурами)...Даже если это будет коллекция сущностей - то есть объектов, и они так же будут инкапсулировать свое состояние через методы-поведения (а не геторы и сеторы) то опять же они не дадут так просто себя изменить

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну если действовать с подхода CRUD парадигмы с анимичной моделью - вы правы коллекция объектов это просто коллекция объектов...точнее коллекция данных, и они сами беспомощны и не могут защитить себя, тогда нет смысла защищать коллекцию. Я же говорил о смыслах использования ReadOnly* именно когда объект это больше чем набор пропертей. По крайней мере смысла в такой защите намного больше, чем просто кем то сказаная "бестпрактикс"

Comment: @skingreek - я полностью поддерживаю принцип: возвращать максимально конкретное. Если мы возвращаем коллекцию колес, принадлежащих конкретному автомобилю (ссылка на коллекцию хранится в экземпляре машины), то да, нужно возвращать ReadOnly - это и будет в данном случае _максимально конкретное_. Но я возражаю против бессмысленных приведений к IEnumerable и т. п.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99180/discussion-between-skingreek-and-alexander-petrov).

Answer (score 3):

1. Не помню точно где, прочел мысль вида: при построении API придерживается принципа принимайте максимально абстрактное, возвращай максимально конкретное. Этим я думаю и стоит руководствоваться при такого рода выборе.
2. Основано на моих наблюдениях: `IReadOnly*` вообще стоит использовать для защиты инвариантов (и только при возврате значения) хорошо инкапсулированных классов (агрегатов, сущностей и объектов-значений). 
   Пример того, о чем я говорю про инкапсуляция и контроль инвариантов:

Возьмем объект "Машина", мы на ней можем ездить, можем закрывать ее...но нам так же хочется знать, какая резина на ее колесах...мы спрашиваем коллекцию ее колес, она отдает нам неизменяемый список (список, а не IEnumerable, потому что знает что нам будет логично обращаться к конкретному колесу по индексу)...он не модифицируемый, потому что иначе это позволит менять набор колес без ведома самой машины. Это не допустимо потому что машина контролирует инвариант вида 'производитель машины разрешает ставить колеса только диаметром 16-18"'. Опираясь на эти ограничения нам проще контролировать логику системы (нам не приходится опасаться что где то вне логики машины будет произведена модификация, которая нарушит инвариантность и согласованность объекта машины).

В качестве аргументов принимать такой интерфейс бессмысленно вовсе, так как мутировать переданные объекты вообще моветон, только если метод явно не содержит это намерение в своем имени.

Comment: _возвращай максимально конкретное_ - золотые слова! Раньше так и было, но в последнее время, к сожалению, всё чаще вижу, что возвращают тоже абстракции.