# Как понять, когда лучше вернуть List, а когда IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net

Ну с правилом, когда нужно принять наиболее базовый тип- тут все понятно:

Если моему коду не нужна какая-то фича более конкретного типа, то принимаю на вход метода наиболее абстрактный тип.

А вот, как быть с возвращаемым типом? Ведь я не знаю, как пользователь захочет этим пользоваться.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1028659/184217 - вторая часть про возврат. И комментарии почитайте.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну как я понимаю, это холиварный вопрос и кто-то возвращает наиболее абстрактный тип, а кто-то наиболее конкретный?

Comment: [Postel's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) `Будь консервативен в том что отсылаешь, будь либеральным в том, что принимаешь`. Касаемо методов получается, что либеральность нужно проявлять для параметров, а консерватизм для возвращаемых типов.